# Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2020 and when I try to compile my project, I get these errors:

1)

```
 > Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow 
you to disable R8.
```

2. 

```
 Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' property 
'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
> Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, 
property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class 
org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, 
H:\FinalPluginProjectTest\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\release\out))) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@545c8bb4) before task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported
```

3. 

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\bin\java.exe -classpath "H:\gradle-7.0\lib\gradle-launcher- 
7.0.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' property 
'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
> Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, 
property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class 
org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, 
            
H:\FinalPluginProjectTest\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\release\out))) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@545c8bb4) before task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported
```

anybody know what the problem? If I need add some information, write! Please, help if you can, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try move your project folder in C: or D: if you use windows or move root folder if you use linux and try again build